# Profile Manager on Lion and the Workgroup group

Tags: osx-server, server.app, profile-manager

The first few times I set up Lion server, we didn't plan on using the default group named Workgroup - but I now see that Profile Manager will create a workgroup with the name "Workgroup" and short name "workgroup".

- What function does this group server on Lion Server?
- Should I be adding everyone and everything to this group or should I leave it alone for Profile Manager to manage?

I'm tempted to just keep deleting it, but my gut tells me it's there to serve some purpose that I haven't seen documented anywhere. General advice for small servers where the environment has 10-25 users in LDAP - mostly employees and contractors. At present, I see a need for perhaps two actual groups to control access to files / wikis as well as a second for internal files for employees only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICS *local accounts* on the server belong to it